# Power BI: Power Query filter max value based on another column

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

let's say I have the following table:

| Year | Patch | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1.68 | 23.5 |
| 2021 | 1.70 | 25.5 |
| 2022 | 1.75 | 21.5 |
| 2022 | 1.79 | 24.5 |
| 2023 | 1.84 | 25.5 |
| 2023 | 1.89 | 28.5 |

How can I filter in power query the rows with the highest value in column "Patch" based on the year?

Like getting a result like this:

| Year | Patch | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1.70 | 25.5 |
| 2022 | 1.79 | 24.5 |
| 2023 | 1.89 | 28.5 |

Or from another perspective, if I merge the above table with a fact table how can I only merge the only the latest patch base on the year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In DAX use this **calculated table**

```
Summary = 
SUMMARIZE(
    'Table',
    'Table'[Year],
    "Patch", MAX('Table'[Patch]),
    "Value", CALCULATE( 
        MIN('Table'[Value]), 
        'Table'[Patch] = MAX('Table'[Patch])
    )
)
```

[image]

2. In **PowerQuery** you can copy your "Table", group rows by Year returning the latest Patch and then merge the copy with the original "Table" on both Year and Patch to add the Value column.

```
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(
    #"Changed Type", 
    {"Year"}, {{"Patch", each List.Max([Patch]), type nullable number}}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(
    #"Grouped Rows", 
    {"Patch"}, Table, {"Patch"}, "Table", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(
    #"Merged Queries", 
    "Table", {"Value"}, {"Value"})
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I have to do it a step before in power query since there is more transformation to be done. It's just a part of the whole transformation

Comment: Then use the second solution in my answer.